# How to make spawned process know it's not writing to a terminal (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, stdio, spawn, lzma

I'm writing a little wrapper to the `lzma` command in Linux but the program refuses to write to stdout because it believes to be in an interactive terminal:
`lzma: Compressed data cannot be written to a terminal`

This is my code in js

```js
// Compress a given string using the lzma program, and return the compressed contents.

const { spawn } = require('child_process')


const compress = str => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    const lzma = spawn('lzma', ["-z", "-c", "-9"],
        { stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr] })

    lzma.on('error', err => {
        // console.log(`Failed to start lzma: ${err}`)
        reject(err)
    })

    lzma.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        if (code) {
            // console.log(`lzma process exited with code ${code}`)
            reject(code)
        }
        else if (signal) {
            // console.log(`lzma process exited with signal ${signal}`)
            reject(signal)
        }
        else {
            // console.log(`lzma process exited successfully`)
            resolve(compressed)
        }
    })

    lzma.stdin.write(str)
    lzma.stdin.end()

    let compressed = ''
    lzma.stdout.on('data', data => { compressed += data })

})

module.exports = compress
```

How do I override this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line 9 to:

```js
{ stdio: ["pipe", "pipe", "inherit"] })
```

`lzma.stdin` and `lzma.stdout` won't do anything unless they're connected to a pipe.  "inherit" means that if lzma writes to stderr, you'll see it on the calling process's stderr.

See the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I have a doubt, though. A redditor suggested this isn't a good way of doing things, and I quote: "this is writing binary data, and the string channel in a tty isn't binary safe.

it might output a control-c and kill the channel, by example"

What do you think about that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ^C only is in effect if you're on a TTY, and I think the shell handles the keystroke turning it into a signal.  Pipes between processes are binary-safe, or a lot of stuff would break.

Comment: To prove it to yourself, send one of every byte through the pipe using `cat` to echo them back:  https://gist.github.com/hildjj/b794aa0f87cf88b1a8f7416df69acec5

Comment: Thanks, @joe-hildebrand! I don't have enough S.O. fake money to upvote yet but your comments have been very helpful